# Why the curve getting twisted

Tags: bezier-curves

With the plane i have converted to curve. And made the profile i bevel the curve is getting twisted.

As we have XYZ axis. Where this W axis came from

[image]

[image]

[image]

With the **Tilt** option i can rotate but why its twisted.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1) If you first apply the rotation to mesh-plane and converts into a curve then generally this problem happens.
So, if you only need a rectangular curve object, then the best way to ADD a curve-circle > EDIT mode > Press V > set handle type to 'Vector', you have rectangular curve object.

Now the twist problem:-

2) **For circular curve or curve having smooth bends**: Go to Curve properties panel, then change the 'twisting' option from 'minimum' (which is default) to '**tangent**' and for a curve having smooth bends, also adjust the 'smooth' option accordingly. (Note- Spline Type should be '**bezier**')

When the 'twisting' is set to 'minimum' :
[image]

When the 'twisting' is set to 'tangent' :
[image]

3) **For rectangular curve** :

**(a) Rectangular curve from curve-circle:** ADD a curve-circle > EDIT mode > Press V, set handle type to 'Vector' > then again Press V set handle type to 'Free', then go to Curve properties panel, then set 'twisting' option to '**minimum**' and 'smooth' to 50 (adjust accordingly). In this way you have a twist free curve even if you move curve-points in the edit-mode and movement of curve-points only shift the overall tilt of the curve. (Note- Spline Type should be '**bezier**')

[image]

**(b) Rectangular curve from mesh-plane**: If you convert **mesh-plane** to curve object and it has Spline-Type 'poly', therefore twisting option does not work properly. So, go to Edit Mode > Tools > Curve Tools > Set Spline Type to 'Bezier' > Press V, set handle type to 'Vector' > then again Press V set handle type to 'Free'. Then go to Curve properties panel, then set 'twisting' option to '**minimum**' and 'smooth' to 50 (adjust accordingly). (Note- Spline Type should be '**bezier**') 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. But when i tried with my plane converting and change to tangent and tweak smooth setting did not get the result. Can you plz experiment on my plan and show me in .gif recorded way.

Comment: @atek I have updated my answer and as I mentioned in the answer, 'tangent' option works nicely for circular curves and 'minimum' for rectangular curves. For mesh-plane, see '(b) Rectangular curve from mesh-plane' in my answer.

Comment: This is the result im getting according to your steps. https://imgur.com/gallery/fs5a1N4

Comment: @atek I used your blend file and found that after doing all steps, go to EDIT mode > select all the points > rotate them along-x by a very small angle ~ 0.001, that fixes the problem. Can you send me/upload the blend file which has the problem as you mentioned in comment ?

Comment: Did not work for me. And the file i have upload in the question its same im getting the result. I rotated also but did not work

Comment: @atek  but I also used the same file and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to properly set (or reset) the tilt of those control points, being that curve converted from a square mesh.

But if you wish to get that shape, try using a bezier circle, set its control point as "vector", they will behave much better, and probably you'll get what you want:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried to reset pressing Alt+T did not work.